# Display dynamic table on page (re)load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to find a solution for a table that is populated with $.ajax(), but the content doesn't display when the page loads. How can I do that? Maybe there is something missing on my `$.ajax()` function?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 overflow-table">
            <table class="table" id="table">
            <thead class="head-color thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-left:1px solid transparent;">NAME</th>
                    <th>CLIENT-ID</th>
                    <th>URL</th>
                    <th style="border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-right:1px solid transparent;">ACTIONS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id='table-redirect'>
                <tr class='lightgrey'>
                </tr>
                <tr class='lightgrey'>
                </tr>
                <tr class='lightgrey'>
                </tr>
                <tr class='lightgrey'>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

`$.ajax()` function to populate the table when you click a button

```
            //save content to the table
        $('#saveButton').on('click', function() {
            var url = "http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/redirect";
            var name = $('#name').val();
            console.log(name);
            var clientId = $('#clientId').val();
            console.log(clientId);
            var redirectUrl = $('#redirectUrl').val();
            console.log(redirectUrl);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', name);
            formData.append('client_id', clientId);
            formData.append('url', redirectUrl);
            console.log('test')
            $.ajax({
                url: url + "/saveRedirect",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(obj) {
                    var name, clientId, redirectUrl;
                    var rows = '';
                    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        rows += "<tr class='lightgrey'><th>" + obj[i].name + "</th><td>" + obj[i].client_id + "</td><td>" + obj[i].url + "</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal" + obj[i].client_id + "'><img class='col-md-2 edit nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg'></button><div class='modal fade' id='myModal" + obj[i].client_id + "' role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-body'><div class='form-group row'><label for='example-search-input' class='col-2 col-form-label'>&nbsp;Name</label><div class='col-10'><input class='form-control' type='search'  id='name1' name='name1' value='" + obj[i].name + "' required></div></div><div class='form-group row'><label for='example-email-input' class='col-2 col-form-label'>&nbsp;URL</label><div class='col-10'><input class='form-control' type='url' id='url1' name='url1'  value='" + obj[i].url + "' required></div></div><div class='form-group row'><label for='example-url-input' class='col-2 col-form-label'>&nbsp;Client ID</label><div class='col-10'><input class='form-control' type='text' disabled id='client_id1' name='client_id1'  value='" + obj[i].client_id + "'  required></div></div><input type='hidden' value='" + obj[i].id + "' name='hidden' id='hidden'><input type='submit' value='Change' id='change'></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div></div></div></div><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id='" + obj[i].id + "'><img class='col-md-2 link nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg'></a></td></td></tr>";
                        $("#table").append(rows);
                        console.log('sucess!');
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want  to  load data when page reloads..do a ajax call in document  ready function..like below
   $(document).ready(function() {

```
// do ajax call
```

});

Comment: I later figured that your answer was the missing part on my code. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Timmy is does this answer is different from mine ?

Answer (score 1):

As when you click the button then the data is loaded.

You can simply call the function by programmatically clicking the button on the page load like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#saveButton').click();
});
```

**Method 2**

You can bind the ajax call in a function and call that function on the button click as well as call that function on the page load like so:

```
function loadData()
{
            var url = "http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/redirect";
            var name = $('#name').val();
            console.log(name);
            var clientId = $('#clientId').val();
            console.log(clientId);
            var redirectUrl = $('#redirectUrl').val();
            console.log(redirectUrl);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', name);
            formData.append('client_id', clientId);
            formData.append('url', redirectUrl);
            console.log('test')
            $.ajax({
                url: url + "/saveRedirect",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(obj) {
                    var name, clientId, redirectUrl;
                    var rows = '';
                    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        rows += "<tr class='lightgrey'><th>" + obj[i].name + "</th><td>" + obj[i].client_id + "</td><td>" + obj[i].url + "</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal" + obj[i].client_id + "'><img class='col-md-2 edit nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg'></button><div class='modal fade' id='myModal" + obj[i].client_id + "' role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-body'><div class='form-group row'><label for='example-search-input' class='col-2 col-form-label'>&nbsp;Name</label><div class='col-10'><input class='form-control' type='search'  id='name1' name='name1' value='" + obj[i].name + "' required></div></div><div class='form-group row'><label for='example-email-input' class='col-2 col-form-label'>&nbsp;URL</label><div class='col-10'><input class='form-control' type='url' id='url1' name='url1'  value='" + obj[i].url + "' required></div></div><div class='form-group row'><label for='example-url-input' class='col-2 col-form-label'>&nbsp;Client ID</label><div class='col-10'><input class='form-control' type='text' disabled id='client_id1' name='client_id1'  value='" + obj[i].client_id + "'  required></div></div><input type='hidden' value='" + obj[i].id + "' name='hidden' id='hidden'><input type='submit' value='Change' id='change'></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div></div></div></div><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id='" + obj[i].id + "'><img class='col-md-2 link nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg'></a></td></td></tr>";
                        $("#table").append(rows);
                        console.log('sucess!');
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
}
```

now for your button click listener use :

```
$('#saveButton').on('click', loadData);
```

And for the document load use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     loadData();
});
```

Comment: Almost there! I still have one error going on: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null** and if I `console.log(obj)` it returns `null` also

Comment: @Timmy   What are you echoing out from your server ? i.e What is the response ?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but i have inputs to insert data to the table and this error occured when the $.ajax() was triggered on button click and those inputs empty.

Comment: @Timmy What is the actual result of the AJAX request? on which you run the following for loop ? `for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) ` is `obj` an array ? because `.length` works on arrays

Comment: Yes, the obj is an Array, but the result is an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145002/discussion-between-timmy-and-shakti-phartiyal).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are loading the data when the user has clicked on an element with the id "saveButton".

If you want the data to be loaded when the page has loaded do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code thats currently wrapped in the
    // $('#saveButton').on('click', function() { block
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add $('#saveButton').trigger('click);
Below on "$('#saveButton').on('click', function()"